# Android grid view alignment in a layout

Tags: android, gridview

I'm developing a game hangman and it contains A to Z buttons in it everything works fine only problem i'm facing is with the grid view which contains letters from A to Z. When i'm installing the game in mobiles of different screen sizes the grid view consisting of letters are not aligned properly.For small screen mobiles it is enabling scroll automatically and for big screen mobiles it is showing above the bottom margin. I need the grid view to be in fixed position i.e., letters from A to Z should be shown in all types of screen sizes without providing a scroll.The screenshots are below http://tinypic.com/r/2q07otc/8  http://tinypic.com/r/1z1zcwm/8  and my xml code is Please help in solving this so that my assignment completes Thanks in Advance

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="240sp">

<GridView
android:id="@+id/letters"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:horizontalSpacing="5sp"
android:numColumns="9"
android:padding="5sp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="5sp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this `android:numColumns="auto_fit" and android:stretchMode.`